# Why doesn't nginx location check if the uri match any regular expression before prefix check?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

through the nginx doc

> To find location matching a given request, nginx first checks locations defined using the prefix strings (prefix locations). Among them, the location with the longest matching prefix is selected and remembered. Then regular expressions are checked, in the order of their appearance in the configuration file. The search of regular expressions terminates on the first match, and the corresponding configuration is used. If no match with a regular expression is found then the configuration of the prefix location remembered earlier is used.

Why doesn't nginx location check if the uri match regular expression before prefix check ? and i think it's faster than now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot state why the designers implemented Nginx in any particular way, but...

The prefix check is optimised to be very fast.

And, if the `location` identified during the prefix check is marked with the [`^~` modifier](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), scanning the regular expressions is no longer required.